# Get duplicates in collection list of dataframes in the same row in Apache Spark (pyspark 2.4)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In Spark, with pyspark, I have a data frame with duplicates. I want to deduplicate them with multiples rules like email and mobile_phone.

This is my code in python 3 :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

df = sc.parallelize(
    [
        Row(raw_id='1001', first_name='adam', mobile_phone='0644556677', email='adam@gmail.fr'),
        Row(raw_id='2002', first_name='adam', mobile_phone='0644556688', email='adam@gmail.fr'),
        Row(raw_id='3003', first_name='momo', mobile_phone='0644556699', email='momo@gmail.fr'),
        Row(raw_id='4004', first_name='momo', mobile_phone='0644556600', email='mouma@gmail.fr'),
        Row(raw_id='5005', first_name='adam', mobile_phone='0644556688', email='adama@gmail.fr'),
        Row(raw_id='6006', first_name='rida', mobile_phone='0644556688', email='rida@gmail.fr')
    ]
).toDF()
```

My original dataframe is :

```
+--------------+----------+------------+------+
|         email|first_name|mobile_phone|raw_id|
+--------------+----------+------------+------+
| adam@gmail.fr|      adam|  0644556677|  1001|
| adam@gmail.fr|      adam|  0644556688|  2002|
| momo@gmail.fr|      momo|  0644556699|  3003|
|mouma@gmail.fr|      momo|  0644556600|  4004|
|adama@gmail.fr|      adam|  0644556688|  5005|
| rida@gmail.fr|      rida|  0644556688|  6006|
+--------------+----------+------------+------+
```

Then, i apply my deduplication rules :

```
df_mobile = df \
   .groupBy('mobile_phone') \
   .agg(collect_list('raw_id').alias('raws'))

df_email = df \
   .groupBy('email') \
   .agg(collect_list('raw_id').alias('raws'))
```

This is the result i have :

```
df_mobile.select('raws').show(10, False)
+------------------+                                                            
|raws              |
+------------------+
|[2002, 5005, 6006]|
|[1001]            |
|[4004]            |
|[3003]            |
+------------------+

df_email.select('raws').show(10, False)
+------------+
|raws        |
+------------+
|[3003]      |
|[4004]      |
|[1001, 2002]|
|[5005]      |
|[6006]      |
+------------+
```

So, the final result I want is to regroup common elements of the raws column like this :

```
+------------------------+
|raws                    |
+------------------------+
|[3003]                  |
|[4004]                  |
|[2002, 5005, 6006, 1001]|
+------------------------+
```

Do you know how I can do it with pyspark ?
Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. You may want to look into [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html)

Comment: So do you think there is no way to do this just with spark SQL ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: You have to think of this as a connected component problem. There's isn't a simple sparksql query that will handle the general case.

Comment: Thank you, i'm now exploring the solution gived by @Frank Wilson to understand Connected Components.
Thanks again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems as @pault is hinting at you could model this as a graph where your original dataframe `df` is a list of vertices and `df_email` and `df_mobile` are lists of connected vertices. Now unfortunately GraphX is not available for python, but [GraphFrames](https://graphframes.github.io/) is!

GrameFrames has a function called [Connected Components](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components) that will return the list of connected `raw_ids` or vertices. To use it we must do two things, `raw_id` must be just called `id` and the edge must be source (src) and destination (dst) pairs not simply lists of vertices.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from graphframes import GraphFrame

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("checkpoints")
    # graphframes requires a checkpoint dir since v0.3.0
    # https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html#connected-components

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN") # make it easier to see our output

vertices = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1001', 'adam', '0644556677', 'adam@gmail.fr'),
    ('2002', 'adam', '0644556688', 'adam@gmail.fr'),
    ('3003', 'momo', '0644556699', 'momo@gmail.fr'),
    ('4004', 'momo', '0644556600', 'mouma@gmail.fr'),
    ('5005', 'adam', '0644556688', 'adama@gmail.fr'),
    ('6006', 'rida', '0644556688', 'rida@gmail.fr')
]).toDF("id", "first_name", "mobile_phone", "email")

mk_edges = udf(
    lambda a: [{'src': src, 'dst': dst} for (src, dst) in zip(a, a[-1:] + a[:-1])],
    returnType=ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField('src', StringType(), nullable=False),
        StructField('dst', StringType(), nullable=False)])))

def edges_by_group_key(df, group_key):
    return df.groupBy(group_key) \
        .agg(collect_list('id').alias('ids')) \
        .select(mk_edges('ids').alias('edges')) \
        .select(explode('edges').alias('edge')) \
        .select("edge.*")

mobileEdges = edges_by_group_key(vertices, 'mobile_phone')
print('mobile edges')
mobileEdges.show(truncate=False)

# mobile edges
# +----+----+
# |src |dst |
# +----+----+
# |2002|6006|
# |5005|2002|
# |6006|5005|
# |1001|1001|
# |4004|4004|
# |3003|3003|
# +----+----+

emailEdges = edges_by_group_key(vertices, 'email')
print('email edges')
emailEdges.show(truncate=False)

# email edges
# +----+----+
# |src |dst |
# +----+----+
# |3003|3003|
# |4004|4004|
# |1001|2002|
# |2002|1001|
# |5005|5005|
# |6006|6006|
# +----+----+

g = GraphFrame(vertices, mobileEdges.union(emailEdges))

result = g.connectedComponents()
print('connectedComponents')
result.select("id", "component") \
    .groupBy("component") \
    .agg(collect_list('id').alias('ids')) \
    .select('ids').show(truncate=False)

# connectedComponents
# +------------------------+
# |ids                     |
# +------------------------+
# |[1001, 2002, 5005, 6006]|
# |[4004]                  |
# |[3003]                  |
# +------------------------+
```

There might be a cleverer way to do the union between the mobile and email dataframes, maybe deduplicate with distinct, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the work you did to help me.
I'm gonna try this but i must admit that i do not have experience with graph and i'm a beginner with spark.
I was hoping that there is a solution with spark SQL. if you think there is obvious solution, i'm gonna try to implement this graph solution.
Thank you very much again.

Comment: I used your solution and it worked well !
Thank you very much again.